# Getting ligatures to work outside of comments

Tags: font

I'm playing around with [Fira-Code](https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode) and am having a weird issue with its ligatures. They seem to only work within the comments and not within my actual code.

I have no idea what's causing this or how to fix it, suggestions?

[image: example of vim ligatures only working in comments and not code]

results of `gvim --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.0 (2016 Sep 12, compiled Mar 17 2017 12:13:35)
Included patches: 1-95
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version with GTK3 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+arabic          +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
+autocmd         +float           +mouse_urxvt     +tcl
+balloon_eval    +folding         +mouse_xterm     +termguicolors
+browse          -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
++builtin_terms  +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
+channel         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +timers
+cindent         +iconv           +num64           +title
+clientserver    +insert_expand   +packages        +toolbar
+clipboard       +job             +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +jumplist        +perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +keymap          +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +lambda          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con_gui  +lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            +ruby            +X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
+dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           +xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     +xpm
+emacs_tags      +mouseshape      +startuptime     +xsmp_interact
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      +xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax          
+farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary      
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_GTK  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/at-spi-2.0 -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/mirclient -I/usr/include/mircore -I/usr/include/mircookie -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-8krYYf/vim-8.0.0095=. -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -L. -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,-E  -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim   -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpango-1.0 -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lSM -lICE -lXpm -lXt -lX11 -lXdmcp -lSM -lICE  -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl  -L/usr/lib -llua5.2 -Wl,-E  -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24/CORE -lperl -ldl -lm -lpthread -lcrypt  -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -ltcl8.6 -ldl -lz -lpthread -lieee -lm -lruby-2.3 -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm
```

Comment: Have you tried disabling all other plugins?

Comment: gVim is listed in the "doesn't work" column here: https://github.com/tonsky/FiraCode .. Looks like you'll have to use Vim from a terminal (and not all terminals are supported, too! So be sure to check that as well).

Comment: @bvpx: Yup, as long as I explicitly set a colorscheme it works, albeit with the same caveat. They only work in the comments.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: But it does work! The ligatures are rendering fine in the comments and i can't find any other issues. There's a patch floating around that must have been pulled into mainline gvim or something

Comment: I think, what you are seeing in the comments is concealed text. Try `:set conceallevel=0`. Also true ligature support is not possible in vim/gvim (only if your terminal supports it). There is an issue somewhere about that feature request, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt: That's not it, the current debian source package for gvim has the patch that allows for ascii ligatures, but not the patch version that allows you to control what ligatures are expressed outside of certain conditions. The patch is [here](https://github.com/manuelschiller/vim/commit/0c8d6a735f1f6452b11c0da039f8c9c9f125475a), the left side is what the current version of the package uses, the right is what I'd need in order to have ligatures everywhere.

Comment: @Jello_Raptor To the best of my knowledge, this is not true. [here](https://anonscm.debian.org/cgit/pkg-vim/vim.git/tree/debian/patches) are the current debian patches. None of it has to do with ligature support.